# Code First - Handle concurrency of select maximum value in a table

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, ef-code-first, code-first

I have a class that has a 'code' property. it's not a unique property also. it is a part of composite unique key. I have to get the maximum value of it and add one to it and save it to table as a new row. this operation occurs many times and I concern about concurrency. two user read same max value and both of them add one and save to database. how can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Option A)
use another table with an int Key that supplies this value.
The value might not get used if a commit fails, but at least you can be sure the value is the next number from a range.

Option B)use a "pessimistic" lock scenario you can try and use the underlying DB. 
in SQL server [Get app lock in SQL server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189823.aspx)

Making sure the app lock is properly managed, can be reset of thread fails etc makes 
application style locks more problematic. If you can deal with occasionally non sequential values, use A.